# Magento 2 - How to call some api when adding or updating a product via admin panel

Tags: php, api, magento, magento2

I want to call an api whenever I add a new product to the catalog or update any product, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZjJr.png).

Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: Are you on Magento 1 or Magento 2? Cause the solution will be different.

Comment: you can solve this with observer; example: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93986/3359

Comment: magento 2, it's written in the title @GerarddeVisser

Comment: @Suraj Thx for clarification. See my added answer what should work for your case.

Comment: @GerarddeVisser it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Suraj: That's great! Can you accept / upvote the answer to let future visitors know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an observer on the event `catalog_product_save_after` for this.

You needs these files for this in your project:

app/code/Company/Module/registration.php:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Company_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/module.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Module"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/etc/events.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="company_module_product_save_after" instance="Company\Module\Observer\Catalog\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Company/Module/Observer/Catalog/ProductSaveAfter.php:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Company\Module\Observer\Catalog;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        Observer $observer
    ): void {
        // Your code logic here, like:
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $productData = $product->getData();
    }
}
```

After this run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` from command line to enable the module.